# How do I do something after a specific Websocket.send() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send a POST request after sending a message to a websocket.
Ive tried call baks like this :

```
socket.send(message,function(){...});
```

and

```
function sendsocket(message,callback){
socket.send(message);
callback;}
```

and call it like

```
sendsocket(message,function(){....});
```

doesnt work !!!

please help

Answer (score 1):

Your first method doesn't work because [`send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) does not accept a callback argument.

You forgot to call the callback method in the second method. It should be:

```
function sendsocket(message,callback){
  socket.send(message);
  callback();
}
```